# Run python script at reception of email

Tags: python, cron, shared-hosting

I own a shared hosting which can run anacrontab. I would like to run a python script when I receive an email on that server. 
Is anacrontab enough? 
Or would using a client such as Gmail be better?

Comment: As a user, look into using procmail to pass emails that match some condition to a piped command. If you administer the mail server you could create a milter (mail filter) if this is for multiple accounts.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestion for a source where to learn how to use procmail for this task?

Comment: Searching "filter mail with procmail" yields http://www.linux-mag.com/id/826/ as a likely candidate. You need a rule that uses a pipe into some script.

Comment: I actually can't install procmail on my server. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import imapclient, pyzmail, html2text

def latestMail():
    imapObj = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.yourServer.com', ssl=False)
    imapObj.login('imapUser', 'imapPass')
    imapObj.select_folder('Inbox', readonly=False)
    UIDs = imapObj.search(criteria='ALL', charset=None)
    rawMessages = imapObj.fetch(UIDs[0], ['BODY[]', 'FLAGS'])
    message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessages[UIDs[0]]['BODY[]'])
    return message

def parser(message):
    if message.text_part is not None and message.html_part is not None:
        multipart = True
    else:
        multipart = False

    if message.text_part is not None:
        try:
            body = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
        except TypeError:
            body = message.text_part.get_payload()

    if message.html_part is not None and multipart is False:
        try:
            body = html2text.html2text(message.html_part.get_payload().decode(message.html_part.charset))
        except Exception:
            raise Systemexit
    return body


try:
    message = latestMail()
    clean = parser(message)
    print clean
except IndexError:
    print "No messages left"
    raise os._exit(0)
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Crontab config:

```
HOME=/var/www/html/whatever
* * * * * root /var/www/html/whatever/myMailChecker.py
```

Conclusion:

This will call your imap servers' Inbox every minute and parse trough your mail and parse it's content, you can do whatever you want after like create a new entry in your mysql table with the mail content etc.. or run another script if clean `is not None` etc.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have Crontab on my server, only anacrontab, so I'm not sure this would work for me.

Comment: No problem, you can completly skip Cron by writing your own Cron version in about 10-15 lines of code

Comment: Oh cool, thanks! Do you know where I could find info / what search I should do to know more about this?

Comment: Sure start with `from subprocess import call` calling a python program looks like this: `subprocess.check_call('python myApp.py', shell=True)`

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider voting it up/accepting as answer.